# HTML text in react native app, how to include?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a magazine app, some of the content is pulled from a server and come HTML formatted (mostly `<P>` `<I>` `<B>` and so on... no complex DIV structure or CSS styling). I want to keep the HTML format because it is relevant to the content, but it looks (despite searching a lot) there is no easy and straightforward way to include HTML text in the app; I tried webview (but did not render anything!). **webviewquilljs** gave me some errors-- *react-native-render-html* but had a lot of error...
any suggestion?

Comment: With `react-native-webview` When you create a WebView, you need to specify in style props the width and height. For example:

<WebView
  style={{width:  300, height: 300}}
  source={{ html: '<html>test</html>'}}
/>

Answer (score 0):

with a bit of pain i finally had react-native-render-html working